# collect all the nested sublinks from the master link of a url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scraper

I am trying to use beautiful soup for getting all the href from a master link.
Suppose master link a has b,c,d,e,.... as sublinks inside the webpage.
Now i want to go to b and collect b1,b2,b3,....
same for c and d and so on...

I had written the code to get these links but ending up adding more n more for loops...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2

#extracing links from main/master link    
r = requests.get("http://www.example.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
links = soup.find_all("a")
href_link={}
for link in links:
    if "https" in link.get("href"):
        key = link.get("href")
        value = link.text
        href_link[key]=value
        print(key)

#extract links from all the sublinks and so on from master link    
href_sublink={}
for k,v in href_link.items():
    r = requests.get(k)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
    links = soup.find_all("a")
    for link in links:
        c = link.get("href");
        if c is not None and ("https" in c or "http" in c):
            key = link.get("href")
            value = link.text
            href_sublink[key]=value
            print("---",key)
print("------all the sublinks are below-----------")        

link_dict =  href_link.copy()
link_dict.update(href_sublink)
```

Is there any better way to collect all the sublinks in more effective manner?

Answer (score 0):

I can not claim this is more effective manner. However i can say that you are not collecting all links. Because all links will not have absolute path. Some of them will be appended to base url. You can use url joins to get absolute url. but here is how i do it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

master_request = requests.get("http://www.example.com")
master_soup = BeautifulSoup(master_request.content, 'html.parser')
master_atags = master_soup.find_all("a", href=True)
master_links = []
sub_links = {}
for master_atag in master_atags:
    master_href = master_atag.get('href')
    print(master_href)
    master_links.append(master_href)
    sub_request = requests.get(master_href)
    sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_request.content, 'html.parser')
    sub_atags = sub_soup.find_all("a", href=True)
    sub_links[master_href] = []
    for sub_atag in sub_atags:
        sub_href = sub_atag.get('href')
        sub_links[master_href].append(sub_href)
        print("\t"+sub_href)
```

also see urllib.parse